# How can I fix the maven-compiler-plugin config in my pom so that it doesn't break the Eclipse integration?

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, m2eclipse

I am inheriting a project from another developer who uses IntelliJ.  I cannot get Eclipse's maven integration working with the project's pom: the `Maven Dependencies` library is not showing up on the classpath nor are the source folders getting configured based on the pom.

I've isolated the problem to the following plugin entry: when I comment it out, the Eclipse integration seems to work like it should.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- 2.8.0-01 and later require maven-compiler-plugin 3.1 or higher -->
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2-01</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for 2.8.0-01 and later you must have an explicit dependency on groovy-eclipse-batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3-01</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

How can I fix this so that Eclipse won't choke on it?  I am new to maven, and it appears Eclipse's integration is rather finicky and requires a lot of extra "lifecyle mapping" metadata.  I have tried ignoring the above plugin (e.g. by adding the `<?m2e ignore?>` processing instruction right after the `<plugin>` element, [as described here](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/release-notes-17.html#new-syntax-for-specifying-lifecycle-mapping-metadata), but that doesn't seem to solve the issue).

**Versions and other info**

I am using:

- Eclipse 2018.09
- m2e 1.9.1 and m2e-wtp 1.4.0
- Maven 3.6.0
- Mac OS X High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: It's the opposite I think, you should use `<?m2e execute?>`. Or better `<?m2e execute onConfiguration,onIncremental?>`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use such old versions of Eclipse and of m2e? The source code is written in Groovy, not in Java, right? And you are talking about the dependencies specified outside the plugin shown in the POM snippet, right?

Comment: I use those versions because they're they work fine for other projects I'm working on, and I don't typically upgrade a working installation just to upgrade it.  The source code appears to be partially Groovy and partially Java.  Yes, I'm talking about the dependencies specified outside the plugin shown in the snippet (e.g. Spring).  When I have this plugin in the pom, the Eclipse integration breaks in various ways, but when I take it out, it works.

Comment: @KayproII Speed improvements, security reasons and the possibility to give feedback are some reasons to use current versions instead of versions that are no longer maintained (we are not talking about preview, early access or milestones builds). You asked a question because something is not working and said you are not doing an update because everything is working. By the way, the documentation says that the `<?m2e ignore?>` processing instructions must be a child of `execution`, not of `plugin`.

Comment: @howlger No offense, but I didn't post this question to get a lecture about how I should be closely tracking yet another project that's adopted a rapid release cycle. The Eclipse version I'm on isn't even a year old, and I'm actually far ahead of many of my coworkers. If you believe this is fixed in a newer version, do tell.  I stated that my version of Eclipse works fine for the *other* projects I use it for.  I personally use IntelliJ for this project, and am essentially asking this question for a coworker without an IntelliJ license (who's currently using Neon, BTW).

Comment: My thought was the issue may have some relation to the extra configuration Eclipse needs that this project doesn't have. On the placement of <?m2e ignore?> instructions, the documentation says "each instruction...can also be placed in a <plugin> node."

Comment: @KayproII Simple question: Can you reproduce the issue with the current Eclipse version?

Comment: @howgler If I had tried to reproduce the issue with a different version, I would have mentioned it.  Also, could you please delete all your comments about versions and upgrading?  I think they're distracting from the actual question here.

Comment: @KayproII Eclipse m2e uses the embedded Maven to resolve dependencies. With Eclipse 2019-06 containing m2e 1.12 containing Maven 3.6.1 the described issue can not be reproduced and also `<?m2e ignore?>` works as expected.